# How do you assign a sequence value to a variable?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to assign a sequence value to a variable for use later after the sequence value has been incremented.  I've tried this but it gives an error:

```
variable imageID number;
select SEQ_IMAGE_ID.CURRVAL into :imageID from dual;

select * from IMAGES where IMAGE_ID = :imageID;


Error starting at line 2 in command:
select SEQ_IMAGE_ID.CURRVAL into :imageID from dual
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
01006. 00000 -  "bind variable does not exist"
```

I have triple checked that the sequence name is correct, any ideas?

Comment: Is this SQL*Plus or a PL/SQL environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be doing this in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, from the `variable` declaration. You need to do the assignment in a PL/SQL block, either with an explicit `begin`/`end` or with the `exec` call that hides that:

```
variable imageID number;
exec select SEQ_IMAGE_ID.CURRVAL into :imageID from dual;
select * from IMAGES where IMAGE_ID = :imageID;
```

If you're using 11g you don't need to `select`, you can just assign:

```
variable imageID number;
exec :image_id := SEQ_IMAGE_ID.CURRVAL;
select * from IMAGES where IMAGE_ID = :imageID;
```

You could also use a substitution variable:

```
column tmp_imageid new_value image_id;
select SEQ_IMAGE_ID.CURRVAL as tmp_imageID from dual;
select * from IMAGES where IMAGE_ID = &imageID;
```

Note the change from `:` to indicate a bind variable, to `&` to indicate a substitution variable.

Comment: Perfect.  All I needed was the exec, but it's always good to more fully understand the options.

Comment: I would like to use the variable in an insert statement, but I got this error: `Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1`
What am I missing?

Comment: @AndrasToth - you should ask a new question giving details of exactly what you're doing. There is going to be too much to tack on as commnets to this question.

Answer (score 2):

In PL/SQL, the variable needs to be declared, something like this:

```
declare
  V_IMAGEID;
begin
  select SEQ_IMAGE_ID.CURRVAL into V_IMAGEID from dual;

  select * /*into ... */ from IMAGES where IMAGE_ID = V_IMAGEID;
end;
```

If you're using bind variables, the variable must be bound. The error message indicates this isn't the case. How exactly to bind variables depends on the language/situation. Make sure you use the right direction when binding variables. In the first (dual) query, you will need an out parameter. You may need to specify this.

Answer (score 1):

just remove ':' before :imageId. If you are in a trigger use :new.imageid

the word variable should be removed as well

p.s. I mean anonymous block surely.

Comment: That might not be enough if the sequence has not been accessed in the current session. The OP would get a `ORA-08002` error.

Comment: Ah yes! I should have read the question a bit more closely. `CURRVAL` should therefore be available to his session.